# Want to show data in gridview when click on button

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have  two textboxes, one dropdown and two button's. When I enter value in textboxes, select value from dropdown and press `button1`, my data is stored in the database and I can view that in my grid when I click on `button2`.

But the problem is when I press `button2` without entering any details it should show validation error which I add on my textboxes and dropdown.

**code for aspx.cs**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    string UserName = TextBox1.Text;
    string Password = TextBox2.Text;
    string Role = DropDownList1.Text;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Login(UserName,Password,Role) values('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "','" + Role + "')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", DropDownList1.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    DropDownList1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox1.Focus();
} 
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

**code for aspx**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 178px;
    }
    .style3
    {
        width: 87px;
    }
    .style4
    {
        width: 87px;
        height: 110px;
    }
    .style5
    {
        height: 110px;
    }
</style>
 </head>
 <body style="height: 387px">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
            <tr>
            <td class="style3">
          &nbsp;User name</td>
            <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"> </asp:TextBox>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Enter User Name" Font- Bold="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Password</td>
            <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter Password" Font- Bold="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Select Role</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Manager</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>User</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"  runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Select Role">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
            <td class="style4">
                </td>
            <td class="style5">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Sumit" />

    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" Height="65px" />

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</div>
<p>
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click1" Text="Show" />
                &nbsp;</p>
<p>
```

Comment: @Charles: Its a good edit. able to understand this much better

Answer (score 1):

Please set the validationgroup property for second button to any value like below:

```
validationgroup="xyz"
```

and let me know if problem is still exists.

Comment: @codebrain can u tell you tell me how to put edit and delete link in the gridview to edit the selected column or delete the selected column

Comment: I will add it as a answer ..wait

Answer (score 0):

Check where have you written

```
string.Empty; -> This is making your textbox empty.
```

So you will not be able to access its value on button2_click(). Validation error is thrown since the textbox controls are empty. Have breakpoint and check what goes wrong and correct it.

**Suggestion**

Using **nbsp;** for space in markup will render your page differently in different browsers. I suggest you to use

```
<span style="margin:0 0 0 20px"> Some text here</span>
```

for inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give `ValidationGroup` to the controls which you want to validate.
By Using this property you can set validation over particular controls.
Try to do like this. And let me know if this solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting causesvalidation property to true for button if u want validation to occur on client side..

```
  Causesvalidation=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark up for DELETE: [I have added my samples, Nevermind to change it]

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="modify">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgmodify" CommandName="modify" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/database/images/edit.jpg" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>

 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("catID") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="~/database/images/DeleteRed.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code:

```
 protected void gvcat_rowcmd(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "modify")
    {
        //Your edit code here..
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "editpopup();", true);
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        //Your delete code here
        categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Session["cat"] = categoryID;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "showpopup();", true);
    }
}
```

To delete the row :

```
 if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
      int productcode = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string Cond = "Pid=" + productcode;
        DataRow[] mrow = dtCartItems.Select(Cond);
        if (mrow.Length > 0)
        {
            mrow[0].Delete();
        }
        dtCartItems.AcceptChanges();
        mrow = dtCartItems.Select();
        gridbind();
     }
```

Comment: I only added sample here the delete mechanism should be implemented on your requirement..The **code** is to trigger a Javascript function and The **Delete** part wil delete the row

Comment: i added delete and edit link in my gridview what i want is when i click on edit link selected row data went to the two textboxes where i edit details and when i click on edit link submit button change to update button so that when i make changes in it and click on update button it will update details

Comment: Did you check my answer it will help you in delete..edit is easy you can google it !

Comment: dt is datatable,.. this is a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    string UserName = TextBox1.Text;
    string Password = TextBox2.Text;
    string Role = DropDownList1.Text;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Login(UserName,Password,Role) values('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "','" + Role + "')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", DropDownList1.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    DropDownList1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox1.Focus();
} 
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```